# Do Linux JVMs actually implement Thread priorities?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-priority

Wrote a quick Java proggy to spawn 10 threads with each priority and calculate pi (4*atan(1) method) with BigDecimals 500,000 times each, join on each thread and report the elapsed time for run method.  Yeah, prob'ly not the best example, but keeping it basic.

I'm aware of [Bug4813310](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4813310)

It is non-trivial to do in C, but can we assume that native priorities are never set on Linux JVMs?

```
$uname -r && grep bogomips /proc/cpuinfo
2.4.33.3
bogomips        : 4312.26
$java -version 2>&1 |head -1
Java version "1.6.0_01"
$javac T.java && java -Xmx32m -XX:+UseThreadPriorities T
1:3112
2:2636
3:2662
4:3118
5:2870
6:3319
7:3412
8:3304
9:3299
10:3069
```

Looks like not much of a deviation that one would expect!  That was on a small virtual Linux machine.  Maybe just Sun's?  We shall try IBM J9 VM:

```
1:4091
2:4142
3:3957
4:3905
5:3984
6:3985
7:4130
8:4055
9:3752
10:4071
```

The gross numbers look pretty good in comparison, but there is no scale to the numbers from a thread priority perspective.

Let's try 500k iterations on a 2.6 kernel with an older Sun JVM, one that is constantly loaded with load averages rarely below 7:

```
$uname -r && grep bogomips /proc/cpuinfo
2.6.9-67.ELsmp
bogomips        : 3992.93
bogomips        : 3990.00
$java -version 2>&1 |head -1
java version "1.4.2_14"
$javac T.java && java -Xmx32m -XX:+UseThreadPriorities T
1:63200
2:64388
3:62532
4:58529
5:62292
6:64872
7:64885
8:64584
9:61653
10:61575
```

Let's try IBM's J9 on a real slab just with 2.6 kernel and since a bigger system I'll increase iterations to 2,000,000.

```
$uname -r && grep bogomips /proc/cpuinfo
2.6.9-78.ELsmp
bogomips        : 5989.03
bogomips        : 5985.03
bogomips        : 5985.01
bogomips        : 5985.02
bogomips        : 5984.99
bogomips        : 5985.02
bogomips        : 5984.99
bogomips        : 5985.02
$java -Xmx32m T # this is the IBM J9
1:1718
2:1569
3:1989
4:1897
5:1839
6:1688
7:1634
8:1552
9:2027
10:1522
```

Some great times, but still no apparent thread/process priorities.

Let's try a Windows box.  I know that Windows has a fairly aggressive thread priority scheme.  Anything above *normal* anecdotaly consumes much more.  As such, let's move to 900,000 iterations in each thread:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_11"
C:\>java -Xmx32m T
1:12578
2:12625
3:11469
4:11453
5:10781
6:8937
7:10516
8:8406
9:9953
10:7391
```

Very much what we're looking for, no?

**So Linux JVM's apparently don't have thread priority?**  I understand that you can't really renice to a lower nice level in C, but I would assume JVM engineers would have figured out how to keep a low-niced dispatcher of sorts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the JDK 8 source code, a [comment reads](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l3907):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// thread priority support

// Note: Normal Linux applications are run with SCHED_OTHER policy. SCHED_OTHER
// only supports dynamic priority, static priority must be zero. For real-time
// applications, Linux supports SCHED_RR which allows static priority (1-99).
// However, for large multi-threaded applications, SCHED_RR is not only slower
// than SCHED_OTHER, but also very unstable (my volano tests hang hard 4 out
// of 5 runs - Sep 2005).
//
// The following code actually changes the niceness of kernel-thread/LWP. It
// has an assumption that setpriority() only modifies one kernel-thread/LWP,
// not the entire user process, and user level threads are 1:1 mapped to kernel
// threads. It has always been the case, but could change in the future. For
// this reason, the code should not be used as default (ThreadPriorityPolicy=0).
// It is only used when ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 and requires root privilege.
```

...

[Later on](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l3943), we see:

```
static int prio_init() {
  if (ThreadPriorityPolicy == 1) {
    // Only root can raise thread priority. Don't allow ThreadPriorityPolicy=1
    // if effective uid is not root. Perhaps, a more elegant way of doing
    // this is to test CAP_SYS_NICE capability, but that will require libcap.so
    if (geteuid() != 0) {
      if (!FLAG_IS_DEFAULT(ThreadPriorityPolicy)) {
        warning("-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy requires root privilege on Linux");
      }

      ThreadPriorityPolicy = 0;
    }
  }

  if (UseCriticalJavaThreadPriority) {
    os::java_to_os_priority[MaxPriority] = os::java_to_os_priority[CriticalPriority];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

...

And [subsequently](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l3961):

```
OSReturn os::set_native_priority(Thread* thread, int newpri) {
  if ( !UseThreadPriorities || ThreadPriorityPolicy == 0 ) return OS_OK;

  int ret = setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, thread->osthread()->thread_id(), newpri);
  return (ret == 0) ? OS_OK : OS_ERR;
}
```

So! At least on Sun Java, on Linux, you won't see thread priorities unless you have done `-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy` and that seems to require root.

Comment: I thought that too.  Switching to root with UseThreadPriorities affected nothing.

However, as root and `-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1` yeilds:

1:3809
2:3587
3:3679
4:3223
5:2796
6:2686
7:2233
8:1895
9:1759
10:2311

Looking good :)

Comment: give -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy a value != 0 and != 1 will also let you raise a threads prio

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark here, but wouldn't having prioritized threads in the JVM require having the ability to adjust the priority of the operating system threads?

Linux (and any Unix-like OS) limits the ability to give processes higher priority to root. I would think there would be a similar limitation on threads.

Comment: True, you can renice yourself UP, just not down.  I would think however a dispatch thread/process could renice the 10 levels UPWARDS of where one is.  Maybe even (gasp) have a separate root daemon that would assign priorities for JVM threads.

Comment: I don't know about Java, but in .NET, managed threads are not the same as OS threads, i.e. the CLR schedules threads on its own. Therefore this should be possible for a JVM as well.

Comment: I don't think CLR uses green threads. I'm almost sure thread scheduling is done by the OS.

Comment: According to http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-clr/1844/managed-native-thread-affinity , you can't count on thread affinity between CLR and native threads, though by default the CLR seems to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The default Linux thread scheduler policy SCHED_OTHER does not support priorities. Or to be more exact, it support a priority setting with one value: 0. The other so called 'real time' policies SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR support higher priorities, but are only available to processes with super user privileges.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean from the other code snippet `SCHED_OTHER
// only supports dynamic priority`

Comment: SCHED_OTHER supports niceness only, which is a hint to the scheduler on how to prioritise threads and processes.