# Priority in threads in java

Tags: java

Each time when i run the program the order of execution changes due to max priority assign o thread b it should be started first and completed first the output is  not accordingly

```
threadA.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
threadB.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
System.out.println("Start Thread A");
threadA.start();

System.out.println("Start Thread B");
threadB.start();

System.out.println("End of main Thread");
```

Comment: Is this a question or a fact? And please write in normal font, this one scares me..

Comment: Please state your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java 6, why doesn't higher priority thread not run even if lower priority thread yields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971430/in-java-6-why-doesnt-higher-priority-thread-not-run-even-if-lower-priority-thr)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038592/java-thread-priority-has-no-effect/18308259#18308259

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to quote xagyg's answer:

> Let's keep it simple and go straight to the source ...
>
> Every thread has a priority. When there is competition for processing
>   resources, threads with higher priority are generally executed in
>   preference to threads with lower priority. Such preference is not,
>   however, a guarantee that the highest priority thread will always be
>   running, and thread priorities cannot be used to reliably implement
>   mutual exclusion.
>
> from the Java Language Specification (2nd Edition) p.445. Also ...
>
> Although thread priorities exist in Java and many references state
>   that the JVM will always select one of the highest priority threads
>   for scheduling [52, 56, 89], this is currently not guaranteed by the
>   Java language or virtual machine specifications [53, 90]. Priorities
>   are only hints to the scheduler [127, page 227].
>
> from Testing Concurrent Java Components (PhD Thesis, 2005) p. 62.
>
> Reference 127, page 227 (from the excerpt above) is from Component
>   Software: Beyond Object-Oriented Programming (by C. Szyperski),
>   Addison Wesley, 1998.
>
> In short, do not rely on thread priorities.

[link to the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038592/java-thread-priority-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 1):

Thread priority is a hint to the OS and only matters if you use very high e.g. 100% cpu utilisation on all your CPU.  A thread can run to completion in the time it takes another thread to start.

BTW: You have to be administrator on Windows and `root` or have `setcap` permissions on Linux to raise priority.

In short, changing the priority is next to useless, and cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Are you sure you need to be root/admnistrator? I mean, I know you need to if you want to increase a process priority among other processes, but I always though you wouldn't need when increasing priority of a thread among other threads of the same process.

Comment: @EtienneMiret When you raise the priority of a thread, it is raises against all threads.  Under Linux I think you need permissions to change priority at all, but I am not sure where I read that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a machine with two or more cores running two threads (each assigned to its own core) - which is the usual situation - then thread priority has likely now effect. Every thread will run at maximum single core speed.

Also: You start thread A from your main thread first. Then you start thread B. How fast is you main thread? Is thread A completed faster than starting a thread - thread B?

If you like to ensure order of execution you have to use join, not a priority.

See also [Java Thread priority has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038592/java-thread-priority-has-no-effect/18308259#18308259)