# Does Java thread priority affects scheduling of threads in other JVMs (processes) on the same OS

Tags: java, linux, scheduling, thread-priority, nice

When setting a Java thread to [min priority](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) I know it results in more scheduling time for fellow threads within the same JVM. I'd like to know if threads in other JVM processes will get more scheduling time as well?
In other words, does thread priority affects scheduling regardless of processes scopes?

I know OS might matter, so I'll say I care about Java6 on Linux mostly.

Comment: No; such priority is internal to one JVM instance (process), and has little to no influence on the underlying OS' scheduler.

Comment: @robbmj Are you sure? Java uses native threads now. That was true with green threads.

Comment: Yes, I had to look into this a little while back. If I can find the documentation I referenced I will post an answer.

Comment: I'd like to close this question after running some experiments that showed me that priorities doesn't make a big diff even within the same process. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038592/java-thread-priority-has-no-effect

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662185/do-linux-jvms-actually-implement-thread-priorities