# Higher priority thread getting the same CPU amount as the lower priority?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-priority

Following is my code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PrintingThread a = new PrintingThread("A");
        a.setPriority(9);
        PrintingThread b = new PrintingThread("B");
        b.setPriority(1);
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }

    static class PrintingThread extends Thread {
        private int i = 0;
        private String name;

        public PrintingThread(String name) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                i++;
                if (i % 100000 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Thread " + name + " count=" + i
                            + ". Time :" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Since I have set a higher priority to A, I expected that the print statement would give a higher value for A, but this is not the case. Following is a sample output after running the program for a while.

```
Thread A count=1033300000. Time :1431937330486
Thread A count=1033400000. Time :1431937330486
Thread A count=1033500000. Time :1431937330486
Thread A count=1033600000. Time :1431937330486
Thread B count=1058600000. Time :1431937330485
Thread B count=1058700000. Time :1431937330487
```

I am on Ubuntu and running Java version 1.7.0-79-b15.
I ran the program using the command

```
taskset 0x00000001 java -jar Untitled.jar
```

and have verified using the System Monitor UI that only one CPU is being used(if I execute the command `java -jar Untitled.jar` two CPUs are used).

Does this mean that there is no difference even if I set the priority? Or is there something wrong with my program?

Comment: Your answer actually lies [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662185/do-linux-jvms-actually-implement-thread-priorities). I had missed the *linux OS* part.

Comment: Logic of your program should never depend on Thread priority, its something you cannot reply upon and is likely to perform different then expected.

Comment: @NitinDandriyal Thanks for the pointer Nithin. The reason why I needed to know this was to compare the Java SE and RTSJ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program is fine.

Setting *priority of threads* is just a *hint* to the underlying OS (from your code) asking it to *try and increase the priority of the thread*. There is no guarantee (it is not even necessary) that the OS will do something based on your call.

You could see a *difference* if this program is run under different circumstances (CPU load) or different platform (but *expected* results might not be *consistent*).

Note : On Linux systems, thread priorities are *not considered* by default. You have to use `XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy` option to enable *thread priority* on Linux,